# How to count prices in Arraylist and showing the checked items in another page (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml

My application has three files of xml and two java files. I almost done the work on it but I stuck on the step of making the app counting the prices of meals that checked by users and also appear the name of meals chosen in the invoice page. I will show you the codes and what I want to know is how to make the app count the prices and showing the total price when the user click on the Count total button and appear it on tv_result that is in the invoic_page. Also I want to know how to show the name of meals that checked on (checkedItems) in the invoic_page?

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sahora.al_baik.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Count Total"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/findSelected"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listView1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**food_info.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:text="CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**invoic_page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Checked"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkedItems"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tv_result"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Generate list View from ArrayList
        displayListView();
        checkButtonClick();
    }

    private void displayListView() {

        //Array list of foods
        ArrayList<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<Food>();
        Food food = new Food("15 SAR", "Chicken Meal", false);
        foodList.add(food);
        food = new Food("10 SAR", "Sliced Chicken", false);
        foodList.add(food);
        food = new Food("20 SAR", "Sandwich Chicken", false);
        foodList.add(food);
        food = new Food("10 SAR", "Hot Chicken", false);
        foodList.add(food);
        food = new Food("6 SAR", "Grilled potatoes", false);
        foodList.add(food);
        food = new Food("2 SAR", "Pepsi", false);
        foodList.add(food);
        food = new Food("17 SAR", "Fish Meal", false);
        foodList.add(food);

        //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
                R.layout.food_info, foodList);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }

    private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {

        private ArrayList<Food> foodList;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                               ArrayList<Food> foodList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, foodList);
            this.foodList = new ArrayList<Food>();
            this.foodList.addAll(foodList);

        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView price;
            CheckBox name;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.food_info, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
                holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Food food = foodList.get(position);
            holder.price.setText(" (" + food.getPrice() + ")");
            holder.name.setText(food.getName());
            holder.name.setChecked(food.isSelected());
            holder.name.setTag(food);

            return convertView;

        }

    }

    private void checkButtonClick() {

        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setContentView(R.layout.invoic_page);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Food.java**

```
public class Food {

    String price = null;
    String name = null;
    boolean selected = false;

    public Food(String price, String name, boolean selected) {
        super();
        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

Sorry I'm beginner in coding ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Add a setOnCheckedChangeListener to the checkbox

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.food_info, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Food food = foodList.get(position);
        holder.price.setText(" (" + food.getPrice() + ")");
        holder.name.setText(food.getName());
        holder.name.setChecked(food.isSelected());

        holder.name.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            food.setSelected(b);
        }
       });
        holder.name.setTag(food);

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Make the foodList as global. On click of button

```
private void checkButtonClick() {

    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            setContentView(R.layout.invoic_page);
            int totalPrice = 0;
            for(Food f : foodList){
                if(f.isSelected){
                totalPrice += f.getPrice();
                }

             //totalPrice variable now has the total of all selected items
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Some errors appears to me after adding the new codes... Please what should I do?

Comment: Here is the errors:

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dw3f.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7LgE.png